# IE8 Compatibility View breaks asp:menu

Tags: asp.net, ie8-compatibility-mode, aspmenu

I need to have my ASP.NET web application support both 8 and prior versions of the IE browser.  However, when I click the "broken page" button on my IE8 address bar to switch to Compatibilty View, menu background images are cropped, there is a vertical gap between two menus and a gap between my asp:menu bar and a navigation user control above it.

Regular IE8 view:

[image]

Compatibility View:
[image]

The general format of each menu is:

```
<asp:TableCell ID="tcFurnMenuSectls" runat="server">
    <asp:Menu ID="menuFurnSectls" runat="server" StaticDisplayLevels="1" MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="1"
        Orientation="Horizontal"
        CssClass="FurnMenuSectionals" StaticMenuItemStyle-ItemSpacing="0px"
        DynamicMenuItemStyle-CssClass="FurnMenuDynamicItem"
        StaticMenuItemStyle-CssClass="FurnMenuStaticItem"
        DynamicHoverStyle-CssClass="FurnMenuDynamicItemHover"
        DynamicVerticalOffset="0"
        StaticHoverStyle-CssClass="FurnMenuStaticItemHoverSectls"
        StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage="false"
        DynamicPopOutImageUrl="~/Images/AppMenu/menu_arrow_grey.gif" DynamicMenuItemStyle-VerticalPadding="2" 
        DisappearAfter="0" OnMenuItemClick="menuFurn_MenuItemClick">
        <Items>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Sectionals&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" ImageUrl="~/Images/AppMenu/FurnMenuGradientTransparent.png" Selectable="false">
                <asp:MenuItem Text="Options&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"
                    Value="Sectionals_Options" NavigateUrl="~/FurnMain.aspx?_page=OptsSectl&_title=SectionalOptions">
                </asp:MenuItem>
                <asp:MenuItem
                    Text="Latest deals&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"
                    Value="Sectionals_Deals"
                    NavigateUrl="~/FurnMain.aspx?_page=DealsSectl&_title=SectionalDeals"></asp:MenuItem>
            </asp:MenuItem>
        </Items>
    </asp:Menu>
</asp:TableCell>
```

If I select View -> Source, save the generated HTML and compare the two results, the only difference is in a property of the upper ("Client Home") user control:

```
<table id="topNavCtrl_menuTopNav" class="TopNavMenu topNavCtrl_menuTopNav_2" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="margin-top:-2px;">
```

In the "compatibility" version, margin-top is -3px, instead of -2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see is IE7 rendering of the page, which obviously breaks a few things. You should be able to fix most of these issues using simple CSS tricks/hacks, such as specifying "zoom: 1", margins and "position:relative" for problematic elements. If those things fail (or break IE8), considering creating IE7 specific CSS stylesheet. Make sure to use [IE Developer Tools](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=IE+Developer+Tools) to aid in testing.

More useful information can be found [here](http://www.positioniseverything.net/articles/ie7-dehacker.html).

Answer (score 1):

Or if you don't need compatiblity with IE7, you can hide the button by using X-UA-Compatible with the value IE=8.